# SQL: select all customers that have all items expired

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having-clause

Consider the following DB structure

```
customer (id)
invoice (id, customer_id)
invoice_item (id, invoice_id, warranty_expiry)
```

I need to select all customers, where all their items are expired. Here is what I have so far

```
select * from customer c
inner join invoice i on c.id = i.customer_id
inner join invoice_item ii on i.id = ii.invoice_id
where ii.warranty_expiry < NOW()
group by c.id
having COUNT(ii.id) // <---
```

It feels like I should put something in `HAVING` clause, but I don't have an exact count of items for each client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use a `having` clause to ensure that the given customer has all their items expired. This works by moving the check on `warranty_expiry` from the `where` clause to the `having` clause, as follows:

```
select c.id
from customer c
inner join invoice i on c.id = i.customer_id
inner join invoice_item ii on i.id = ii.invoice_id
group by c.id
having max(ii.warranty_expiry >= NOW()) = 0
```

Note that `select *` and `group by` do not go along well (although older versions of MySQL do allow it by default). You should enumerate the columns that you want to retain in the `select` clause *and* in the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the query, because you don't need the `customer` table.  Then I would go for:

```
select i.customer_id
from invoice i join
     invoice_item ii
     on i.id = ii.invoice_id
group by i.customer_id
having max(ii.waranty_expiry) < now();
```

This assumes that `warnty_expiry` is not `null`.  If that is possible, then:

```
having max(ii.waranty_expiry) < now() and sum(ii.waranty_expiry is null) = 0;
```